# Commenting a block in Ansible

Tags: automation, comments, ansible, ansible-template

I'm trying to automate some deployments and I need to comment out some configuration, which essentially comprises of a full block. Is there a way to comment a particular block of code/configuration via ansible playbook?

Answer (score 0):

Commenting a whole block will be very hard. I can't think of a way to do this without a custom written module.

If it is an option, you can remove a block with the [blockinfile](https://galaxy.ansible.com/detail#/role/1475) module, which has an `state: absent` option. Unfortunately it does not have regex option to identify a block, which would be required to identify your commented/uncommented block. If it helps, the `blockinfile` module can create a backup with the original content.

The docs on the galaxy page are a bit broken. See the [github page](https://github.com/yaegashi/ansible-role-blockinfile) for better formatting.

Comment: Thanks!! I created a regex expression and used replace module, it just works well!!